# Bitnami Redmine + Subversion

Tags: svn, redmine

I'm trying to setup subversion with Redmine.

I've installed the Redmine stack, and I see the subversion folder in it.

I've created a repo: svnadmin /svnrepo/ios

Now what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a project in Redmine. In the project's settings, add a repository. Give it the path to what you just created.

Comment: What would I enter as the path: /svnrepo/ios?